# The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist - First Laravel Project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I’m trying to learn a bit of larvel but I’m having some mysql trouble.
From terminal if I run

```
msql > SHOW DATABASES;
```

I get this error

```
The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
```

Googled for a few hours - tried everything.  The common resolve on forums is

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot
```

However that throws the error

```
The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.
I’m on macOS High Sierra v 10.13.6.  I installed mysql via homebrew.
There’s some fundamental database error and I can’t migrate the database because of this or really do anything in the setup tutorials.
```

I don't see anyway to do an mysql_upgrade now.

I’m on macOS High Sierra v 10.13.6.

I installed mysql via homebrew.

There’s some fundamental database error and I can’t migrate the database because of this or really do anything in the setup tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

for me works dump the user anc created it again

Create user:

mysql> CREATE USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Grant permissions:

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO `mysql.infoschema`@`localhost`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)